# Reducing Solr indexing delay

Tags: solr

By default the example Solr application included with version 1.4.1 takes two minutes to process documents sent to the index. I've seen other servers configured to take 3+ minutes. Where can you change change this to zero or 15 seconds?

Answer (score 4):

You need to adjust autocommit option in your solrconfig.xml. By default its:

```
<autoCommit> 
  <maxDocs>2000</maxDocs>
  <maxTime>120000</maxTime> 
</autoCommit>
```

maxTime is what you need, it's in miliseconds.